# Why am I getting E_OUTOFMEMORY?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, direct3d

For some reason the code below will give me a out of memory error. What am I missing?

```
    for(int n = 0; n < 512; ++n)
    {               
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texture_desc = {};
        texture_desc.Width                = 1920;
        texture_desc.Height               = 1080;
        texture_desc.MipLevels            = 1;
        texture_desc.ArraySize            = 1;
        texture_desc.Format               = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        texture_desc.SampleDesc.Count     = 1;
        texture_desc.Usage                = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        texture_desc.BindFlags            = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

        ID3D11Texture2D* target_d3d_ptr;
        HRESULT hr = this->device_ptr->CreateTexture2D(&texture_desc, nullptr, &target_d3d_ptr);
        if(FAILED(hr))
            throw runtime_error(_com_error(hr).ErrorMessage());

        target_d3d_ptr->Release();
    }
```

Comment: what the current n when you've got E_OUTOFMEMORY?

Comment: It is n = 485 when it fails.

Comment: you mention "in release builds": does that mean in debug builds you don't get the error?

Comment: I get it in debug builds as well.

Comment: well, then it looks like `Release()` does not do exactly what one would expect (for some reason I won't try to guess for the moment). maybe it does not release some resources immediately? have you tried using task manager to see whether your memory consumption actually drops after calling `Release()` or grows monotonically until you get the error?

Comment: @Andy Prowl: I don't think the task manager is much use since it's GPU memory it is allocating.

Comment: assuming it is GPU memory then yes, it's not going to be useful. i'm no expert in this field so I don't know if anything similar exists for GPUs, but my suspect is that `Release()` here does not release that memory immediately, maybe it just marks it as "to be released". but again, i might be saying silly stuff - just working by deduction

Comment: @AndyProwl you're actually right, release does not release immediately, and since on the code there's no calls it will never do it. Calling either devicecontext Flush method or some swapchain present (which will flush the device) will cause the resource deletion.

Comment: I just tried with Flush a moment before. Seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have a swap chain in my application since I'm doing windowless rendering. Seems like I need to do Flush every once in a while.

Comment: If you call MapSubresource (for getting data back) it will flush the device as well for information

Comment: @ronag - If a comment above solved your problem, please request whomever solved it to enter their suggestion as an answer, and then please select that answer.  If you solved it yourself, please provide an answer and then select it.  This will take your question out of the "unanswered questions" tab.  Otherwise, please delete your question so it isn't in "unanswered questions".

Comment: @phonetagger: I think I was quite clear with that catfliers suggestion solved it.

Comment: @ronag - Exactly.  But your question will forever show up in the "unanswered questions" tab unless you either delete the question, or select an answer.  Why don't you ask catfliers to submit his suggestion as an answer, so that catfliers can get "paid" for answering your question?

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, but have you considered this: 
1920 * 1080 * 32bits = 8294400 bytes
Now, 8294400 bytes x 485 textures = 3.836 GBytes of memory.
This is right at the limit of a 32bit machine. I don't know if you are coding a 32 or 64 bit program, but if it is 32bit then the maximum virtual memory you can address is a little under 4GB and 512 textures take you over this limit. Considering that Release does not free up this memory immediately, and *if* you are actually coding in 32bit, then it should be clear why you run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not your case but, for example, Microsoft's COM method [`CComObject::CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e31say1.aspx) can return `E_OUTOFMEMORY` (at least in the implementation I can found in my environment, i.e. Visual Studio 2012) and in my opinion it can be misleading.

The COM method is something like the following (in `atlcom.h`)

```
ATLPREFAST_SUPPRESS(6387)
template <class Base>
_Success_(return == S_OK) HRESULT WINAPI CComObject<Base>::CreateInstance(
    _Deref_out_ CComObject<Base>** pp) throw()
{
    // code omitted

    HRESULT hRes = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    CComObject<Base>* p = NULL;
    ATLTRY(p = new CComObject<Base>())
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        // code omitted
    }
    *pp = p;    
    return hRes;
}
ATLPREFAST_UNSUPPRESS()
```

and it seems to me that the above code can return `E_OUTOFMEMORY` even if you have a lot of memory still available: the macro `ATLTRY` just wraps the call to `new` in a try-catch(...) block and so if the constructor of `Base` fails throwing an exception, *any* kind of exception even not related to memory issues, then `p` will be `NULL` and the function will return `E_OUTOFMEMORY`.

Comment: The question was answered in the comments. It turns out the memory on the GPU wasn't being freed immediately. Some action that flushes the command buffer is necessary to inform the GPU that the textures are no longer used.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that catflier provided the answer to this question in a comment:

> release does not release immediately, and since on the code there's no
>   calls it will never do it. Calling either devicecontext `Flush` method
>   or some swapchain present (which will flush the device) will cause the
>   resource deletion